# Raspberry Pi 3 & PyAudio IOError: [Errno Invalid input device (no default output device)] -9996

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, pyaudio, software-defined-radio

I'm am trying to get PyAudio running an SDR (rtl_fm) on my Raspberry Pi 3 and play audio out of the headphone jack. I don't have anything other than the USB SDR as the source fm audio, everything else is stock.

I've followed the instruction on how to install and setup PyAudio, via their site. (https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/)

Here's my current test code:

```
import pyaudio
import subprocess

CHUNK = 1024
WIDTH = 2
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

pipe1a = subprocess.Popen(['rtl_fm', '-f92.5M', '-Mfm', '-s170k', '-Afast', '-l0', '-Edeemp'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe1b = subprocess.Popen(['play', '-r170k', '-traw', '-es', '-b16', '-c1', '-V1', '-'], stdin=pipe1a.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
            channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            output=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    stream.write(data, CHUNK)

print("* done")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
```

It attempts to execute and I get this error:

```
>> python pyaudio_test_1.py
Found 1 device(s):
  0:  Realtek, RTL2838UHIDIR, SN: 00000001

Using device 0: Generic RTL2832U OEM
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyaudio_test_1.py", line 28, in <module>
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 747, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 442, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno Invalid input device (no default output device)] -9996
pi@raspberrypi:~/pyaudio_test $ Found Rafael Micro R820T tuner
Tuner gain set to automatic.
Tuned to 92755000 Hz.
Oversampling input by: 6x.
Oversampling output by: 1x.
Buffer size: 8.03ms
Exact sample rate is: 1020000.026345 Hz
Sampling at 1020000 S/s.
Output at 170000 Hz.
Signal caught, exiting!

User cancel, exiting...
```

I don't know what to make of the IOError.

I also think there might be a setting mismatch on the rtl_fm and pyaudio settings, but I'm still novice and don't know where I'm mismatched since the nomenclature is slightly different.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find a solution to the IOError?

Comment: I didn't. I also never grasped PyAudio structure enough to fully understand how it's functioning. It seems a bit disconnected to me.  So, it'd be awesome if you have any good resources.